# Is there a way to automatically set the cell width to achieve the shortest table within the page?

Tags: tables, size, cell

I want to automatically set the cell width to allow the table height to be kept minimum. There might be 2 or 3 lines of text in a cell, so this is no problem if the table height is the minimum in such an arrangement. But the table also needs to fit in the page layout.

example table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Sample   ID      & From (m) & To (m) & Length (m) & Type  & Comments                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-001 & 112      & 112.9  & 0.9        & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error   sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque   ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta   sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem qu \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-002 & 112.9    & 113.6  & 0.7        & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-003 & 113.6    & 114    & 0.4        & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-004 & 114      & 114.35 & 0.35       & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-005 & 114.35   & 115.1  & 0.75       & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-006 & 115.1    & 116.1  & 1          & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit   voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa   quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt   expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-007 & 116.1    & 116.6  & 0.5        & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-008 & 116.6    & 117.2  & 0.6        & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-009 & 117.2    & 118    & 0.8        & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit   voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa   quae ab illo inventore v                                                                                                \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-010 & 118      & 119    & 1          & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-011 & 119      & 120    & 1          & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit   voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa   quae ab illo inventore v                                                                                                \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-012 & 120      & 120.93 & 0.93       & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-013 & 128.14   & 128.36 & 0.22       & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-014 & 130.9    & 131.1  & 0.2        & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-015 & 134.9    & 135.15 & 0.25       & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-016 & 137.35   & 137.53 & 0.18       & Slice & "Sed ut   perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium   doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl                                     \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-017 & 120.93   & 124.14 & 3.21       & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-018 & 124.14   & 127.14 & 3          & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
ASW-2B-3F-1R-019 & 127.14   & 128.14 & 1          & Slice & "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your question leaves a lot of important questions open. As such, the only possible, rather generic answer is that if you want to minimize the table's height, you have to be willing to maximize its width, i.e., set its width to `\linewidth`. The `tabular*`, `tabularx`, and `tabulary` environments may be suitable. To be able to say more than this, it's important for you to tell us more about the table you need to construct. E.g., are there columns for which automatic line wrapping should be disallowed? And, should the columns for which automatic line wrapping is enabled all have the same width?

Comment: No there isn't as far as I know... but you can implement it (it's not very fast though) see e.g. `balancetwocols` macro in TeXbook, you can probably adapt that somehow. (programming in TeX is hard though, consider making a Lua/TeX hybrid macro.)

Comment: are there columns for which automatic line wrapping should be disallowed? 
No, there is not.

And, should the columns for which automatic line wrapping is enabled all have the same width?
No, not necessarily.

I am trying to find a way that doesn't require arranging the cell widths manually.

Comment: as long as there is a way I can try a hybrid macro. The project I am working on is hybrid (Py/TeX) already...

Comment: tabulary is probably what you want here. But hard to tell without a example.

Comment: Aside from the first row (which can be formatted separately) only one column really needs to be wrapped.

Comment: An example should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}`  You have added a table but that isn't really demonstrating any problem unless we know the current text width and font size. But for that able you could use tabularx with just the last column being X, or no package at all and just use a standard tabular with the last column being `p{3cm}` or whatever you need.

Comment: Unrelated but the natural meaing of `\begin{table}[]` is not to allow the table anywhere, better to use `\begin{table}` (LaTeX does catch this and issue a warning message)

Comment: @John, I can see it is only one column to wrap, it is not the point. I want to use such settings for multiple tables.

Comment: @David, the given table is just an example and does not include the document settings. And if I use static width, it wouldn't be applicable to other tables.

Comment: You can get a rough idea of the relative sizes of two columns by measuring the width of each column formatted as a single line.  But the actual process of wrapping text is so non-linear that an optimal solution can only be found by trial and error.